# What is the difference between UITouch and UIGestureRecognizer?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

This may be a newbie question, but could anyone please explain the difference between UITouch and UIGestureRecognizer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

UITouch represents a finger.

UIGestureRecognizer is a routine that check if the fingers have performed some special gestures.